# If a base class has 2 derived classes, and those classes each have a derived class, can I extend a base method *once* for the most derived classes?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Sorry for the wordy title. Here's pseduocode for the inheritance scheme I am working with, assume C++ and public inheritance:

```
ClassA
ClassB : ClassA
ClassC : ClassA
ClassBB : ClassB
ClassCC : ClassC
```

I want to override a method that is defined in `ClassA` for both `ClassBB` and `ClassCC`. But I can only work with `ClassBB`, `ClassCC`, or a new class.

I know I could extend `ClassA`, but then I'd need to change the definition of `ClassB` and `ClassC` for them (and in turn `ClassBB` and `ClassCC`) to see the change. With that restriction, I think I am stuck with duplicating the override in both `ClassBB` and `ClassCC`. Could there be another way to do it?

Comment: "I know I could extend ClassA, but then I'd need to change the definition of ClassB and ClassC for them" - you'd just have to change the base class, nothing more - "(and in turn ClassBB and ClassCC)" - no, these wouldn't need to be changed.

Comment: I can only work with the most derived classes, or a new class. The other code is frozen (to me).

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a global function template once and invoke it in the definition of your overrided functions in `ClassBB` and `ClassCC`. Then, you would need to write the implenentation only once. Here comes some untested code:

```
struct A
{
     virtual void foo() {}
};
struct B : public A {};
struct C : public A {};

template<typename T>
void foo_impl(T const& t)
{
     //do something with t
};    

struct BB : public B
{
     virtual void foo() { foo_impl(*this); }
};

struct CC : public C
{
     virtual void foo() { foo_impl(*this); }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to access any protected member in your Base class, simply delegate to an external function, possibly a template as recommended in the previous answer.

Otherwise, you can use multiple virtual inheritance:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void foo() {std::cerr << "Base::foo: " << (++i) << std::endl;};
    Base() : i(0) {}
    virtual ~Base() {}
protected:
    int i; // the state that you need to access in foo()
};

class Implement: public virtual Base
{
public:
     void foo() override {std::cerr << "Implement::foo: " << (++i) << std::endl;}
};

class D1: public Base{};
class D2: public Base{};

class DD1: public D1, public Implement
{
public:
    virtual void foo() override {Implement::foo();}
};

class DD2: public D2, public Implement
{
public:
    virtual void foo() override {Implement::foo();}
};

int main()
{
    DD1 dd1;
    dd1.foo();
    D1 &d1r = dd1;
    d1r.foo();
    D1 d1;
    d1.foo();
}
```

One limitation is that you end up with an ambiguous Base class for your DD1 and DD2 instances

Ad suggested by @Ben Voigt, CRPT is a good alternative to resolve the same problem without the limitation of ambiguous base classes:

```
template <class D>
class CRTP
{
protected:
    void foo_impl(D &d) {std::cerr << "CRTP::foo_impl: " << (++d.i) << std::endl;}
};

class DD2: public D2, public CRTP<DD2>
{
public:
    virtual void foo() override {CRTP<DD2>::foo_impl(*this);}
    friend class CRTP<DD2>;
};
```

Comment: Inheritance is a reasonable way to solve this, but using CRTP.  Multiple virtual inheritance is a very complex approach with all sorts of other effects.  Definitely not something to recommend, IMO.

Comment: @BenVoigt very good point. As it might not be obvious to the OP I added it to my answer.

Comment: Oh sorry, CRTP might be the wrong name.  I was thinking of inheritance from the template parameter, which leads to a very straightforward solution.  I guess that's the opposite of CRTP (template parameter identifies the base class, in CRTP it would be the derived class).

Answer (score 0):

Since you've not specified whether or not the function in class `A` is virtual or not, we have two possibilities.

If `foo` isn't virtual, and you don't need to use `BB` with pointers to `A` (the same applies for `C` and `CC`):

```
class A { public: void foo(); }

class B : public A {} // `A::foo` can be accessed from B.

class BB : public B
{
public:
  // Problem (1): `A::foo` can be accesed from B, and `BB::foo` is another function.
  void foo() { <other_behaviour> } 
};
```

To avoid problem (1), you could make `A::foo` private:

```
class A { public: void foo(); }

class B : public A {} // `A::foo` can be accesed from B.

class BB : public B
{
public:
  void foo() { <other_behaviour> } 

private:
   using A::foo; // `A::foo` can't be accessed from B.
};
```

In this case, you have now two functions: `A::foo` and `B::foo`, but `A::foo` can't be accessed from `B`.

If you need to use `BB::foo()` with pointers to `A` (or `B`), or `A::foo` is already virtual:

```
class A { public: virtual void foo(); }

class B : public A {} // `A::foo` can be accessed from B.

class BB : public B
{
public:
  // Problem (2): `A::foo` and `B::foo` are two different functions, but for using `A::foo`,
  // the user must write `A::foo()` to call it, and don't simply `foo()`.
  void foo() { <other_behaviour> } 
};
```

To solve (2), you can do the same, making `A::foo` private with `using`. In both cases, `B` (and `C`) doesn't need to be changed, and in the first case, `A` either.